# Which one consume less battery in Ubuntu (generally Linux) Ethernet cable or Wireless?

Tags: wireless, power-management, ethernet

I am wondering when i want to connect to network, it is better use my wireless adapter or using cable (ethernet adapter), Which one consume less battery?
Sometimes i saw that my battery life was more when i used wireless adapter!
Has anyone any technical knowledge about this concern?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An interesting question. I imaging it would be quite hardware specific though.

Comment: @Oli Really, could you come up with an example?

Comment: All I mean is I expect some hardware to be a lot better at power saving than others. In some laptops, which adaptor is more power efficient from other laptops. I have nothing to base that on, nor any data to back it up. It would be a good experiment though.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to experiment for yourlself, you're free to compare the power consumption rates between the two adaptors. I'd suggest running on AC-only (remove the battery) and using one of the techniques in this question:

- [How do I monitor power consumption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73904/how-do-i-monitor-power-consumption)

The process would be fairly simple. Switch to wireless, leave it tracking for a set period of time. Something meaningful like an hour might be worthwhile. Then switch to wired and repeat.

As I mention in my comments, hardware can vary hugely. My ethernet card might use twice as much power as yours. My wireless card might use even more. Who knows until we've all experimented?

Comment: I think this technique is not a good way to know about power consumption rates between the two adaptors.

Answer (score 0):

After some test on my laptop (Sony VAIO Z Series VPC-Z213GX), i think it is depend on the hardware, in my case, wireless consume less battery than ethernet card (cable).