# Why do I have drastic loss of battery life on upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, 15.10, power-management, battery

I have a dell xps15 9530 with high capacity battery.  On Ubuntu 15.10 I was getting 6-8hrs battery life using intel graphics, but on 16.10 I only get around 2 hours.  Powertop shows 20-30w power usage while idle.

Is there any way to find what is causing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I monitor power consumption?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73904/how-do-i-monitor-power-consumption)

Comment: Just for anyone with a similar issue, I switched to vanilla Ubuntu and the problem was gone.   The issue occurs on Ubuntu-Gnome.  I switch back to the Ubuntu-Gnome partition every few months and apt-get update, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after nearly 12 months, I have solved it.  The problem was the NFC radio on the dell xps was permanently enabled.  In vanilla Ubuntu there does not seem to be a driver, but there is one in Ubuntu Gnome.

Running

```
rfkill block nfc
```

reduced the power consumption by around 8 watts on standby.

Comment: Ubuntu GNOME and Unity come with exactly the same kernels and drivers. However, GNOME may enable Bluetooth by default while Unity doesn't.