# Software to find desktop power usage?

Tags: software-recommendation

Since I have moved from Windows XP to Ubuntu 12.10, I have been constantly blamed for increased electricity bills.(That may be true, but I think the reason is  increase in the time I use my computer, because it is more productive now).

Is there any software that would calculate how much power my computer actually uses?

> Note that I use a Desktop and the Powertop, Powerstat, and Power Statistics programs referenceed  [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/118287/171245) only work for laptops.
>   The answer suggests that for desktop the only solution "then" is to use a **electronic watt-meter**. Has the situation changed in last 2 years?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/73904/how-do-i-monitor-power-consumption

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I measure server power consumption?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13337/how-do-i-measure-server-power-consumption)

Comment: The same tools that works for laptops should work for desktops. Just that laptops usually have more sensors available due the fact that they work over bateries.

Comment: @Braiam laptops use battery, desktops don't. that's why same tools don't work for both.

Comment: It does, the same sensors manufacturers use for laptops they can use it in desktops, just that they do not include them. The reason why doesn't work isn't because they don't have battery is just that makers doesn't consider important to include those kind of sensors in they desktop models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: You can't by software

powertop seems to be fair in this situation

**Use an electronic watt-meter**

In instance check [this link from intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/06/18/measuring-application-power-consumption-on-linux-operating-system)

Answer (score 4):

We have created a terminal tool to monitor CPU frequency/utilization/Temperature. It now also supports monitoring power on Intel CPUs newer than Sandy-Bridge.
You can see the power graph in watts on the bottom as well as on the side bar.
This only reads total CPU power, not per process and not including other components. 
[image]

Comment: You can find the tool here: https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui

Answer (score -1):

powerstat: Power Consumption Calculator for Ubuntu Linux

For that, open your Terminal and enter the below commands.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:colin-king/powermanagement
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install powerstat
```

[image]

This should handle your request...

For more information and how to use check [this](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/02/powerstat-power-calculator-ubuntu-linux/)

Comment: this works for laptop.`aditya@aditya-desktop:~$ sudo powerstat -d 2
[sudo] password for aditya: 
Machine is indicating it is not discharging and hence we cannot measure power usage.`

Comment: It works also if you are working on backup for PC's

Comment: no it doesn't work even on backup power.

Comment: Ok then i think you have to use an electronic watt-meter